Ignore text values from excel table while plotting data
I want to plot a table that has numerical and string values in it. I would like to generate a PDF but to professionally display it, I want all my string values (NM, N/A) as is without having the "#" in the front. When I just type NA or NM, excel interprets them as zero values and the graph will have a line going to zero instead of having a gap. How can I keep my text values and ignore on the plot at the same time??
Thanks

Change your formula to display "N/A" if there is an error instead of "#N/A".  Whatever it is, wrap it in IFERROR, say =IFERROR(your formula, "N/A")

I am manually inserting the values so If i have a formula there and type "N/A, #N/A, etc, the formula will get deleted.

in this case there is nothing you can do.  I'd say it's your punishment for abusing Excel in this way.


Ensure that your #N/A is the error value and not a text string.
Chart Design => Data => Select Data



Hidden and Empty Cells and you can see the various options



I am manually inserting the values so If i have a formula there and type "N/A, #N/A, etc, the formula will get deleted. I already have this set up and I still get a line connecting the dots between the "gaps" except that it does not have a dot.

@JosueCriollo Text will => zero. You need to enter =NA() to have it show the error value. If you have a formula that is returning an error, then use something like =iferror(myformula,NA())
